# Issue with sonataIntlBundle - I can`t install with composer

Tags: php, linux, symfony, composer-php, symfony-sonata

Output from composer (after composer.phar update)

Problem 1
    - Installation request for sonata-project/intl-bundle 2.2.*@dev -> satisfiable by sonata-project/intl-bundle[2.2.x-dev].
    - sonata-project/intl-bundle 2.2.x-dev requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
  Problem 2
    - sonata-project/intl-bundle 2.2.x-dev requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
    - symfony/framework-standard-edition 2.3.x-dev requires sonata-project/intl-bundle 2.2.*@dev -> satisfiable by sonata-project/intl-bundle[2.2.x-dev].
    - Installation request for symfony/framework-standard-edition 2.3.x-dev -> satisfiable by symfony/framework-standard-edition[2.3.x-dev].

My composer.json:

http://pastebin.com/5RcERC6T

My phpinfo():

http://imageshack.us/f/109/ijoa.png/

And also /etc/php5/cgi/php.ini:

...
[intl]
intl.default_locale = pl_utf8
; This directive allows you to produce PHP errors when some error
; happens within intl functions. The value is the level of the error produced.
; Default is 0, which does not produce any errors.
intl.error_level = E_WARNING
...

Is there something else I can do?

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a WAMP or MAMP server, please check that your extension is set in the two php.ini.

Comment: I`m on LAMP. And I have also set extension in /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini.

Comment: It`s uncommented. Scrap of php.ini: [curl]
; A default value for the CURLOPT_CAINFO option. This is required to be an
; absolute path.
;curl.cainfo =

; Local Variables:
; tab-width: 4
; End:

extension=intl.so

Comment: You have to copy all the files (all files starts with icu*):

icudt.dll
icudt46.dll
icuin.dll
icuin46.dll
icuio.dll
icuio46.dll
icule.dll
icule46.dll
iculx.dll
iculx46.dll
icutest.dll
icutest46.dll
icutu.dll
icutu46.dll
icuuc.dll
icuuc46.dll
From:

/bin/php/php5.4.3/
To:

/bin/apache/apache2.2.22/bin/
And you also need to enable intl in php.ini file (uncomment this line):

;extension=php_intl.dll
Don't forget to restart the server.

Comment: I dont have these files on Linux. But when I try install libcu library I get message that I already installed it.                     sudo apt-get install libicu-dev